# How to layout custom UIButton in Interface Builder and drag and drop them in Storyboard scene

Tags: user-interface, layout, uiview

I have several buttons to layout in a Storyboard scene.  However, I want these to be my `CustomButton`.  One of aspects of this button is having a label constrained just above the bottom of the frame.  For this reason, I wish to do layout in Interface Builder.  Is there a way to also define the layout of my UIButton subclass in Storyboard?

Comment: You can put @IBDesignable keyword at the top of your CustomButton class definition. See this [link](http://nshipster.com/ibinspectable-ibdesignable/)

Comment: I don't think this is what I'm looking for.  It seems IB-designable and inspectable allow you to visualize and manipulate facets of your views but not add subviews and create constraints graphically like a generic XIB, is that right?

Comment: You can set constraints between your CustomButton and other uiviews in your storyboard.

Comment: No, I mean constraining elements in the view Hierarchy of the button.